# loading a function onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I have the following piece of code

```
<a onclick="$('#result').load('codes/test.html');$('#result').show();" >XHTML code</a>
```

it loads perfectly the content of test.html in the result div and also make it visible. Until this point all are good. When I try to add a function `prettyPrint()` which apply some modifications on the text and change the code to the following:

```
<a onclick="$('#result').load('codes/test.html');$('#result').show();prettyPrint();" >XHTML code</a>
```

I can't make the prettyPrint() to work, instead if I add `onmouseout="prettyPrint();` it works when I take off my cursor. I don't have experience with javascript and jquery so I don't know what is the real problem, so I would appreciate any help on how to  make prettyPrint to work `onclick`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery why do you bother with inline Javascript? Why not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#myLink').click(function(){
        $('#result').load('codes/test.html', function() {
            $('#result').show();
            prettyPrint();
        });

        return false;
    });
}):
</script>

<a id="myLink" href="#">XHTML code</a>
```

**Edit:**

Fixed code so it calls `prettyPrint()` when load callback is called.

Comment: Yep, -1 too, even if I think like you : "OH MY GOD STOP INLINE JS !"

Comment: @rochal : as the load() is asynchronous, the only reason prettyPrint doesn't work is that it is executed, while #result is still empty.

Comment: @clement, Hmm... good point. PrettyPrint() should be added as a callback

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, @Clement Herreman - check out my modified code.

Answer (score 2):

The load is asynchronous.  When prettyPrint is called, the text might not be there yet.

```
<a onclick="$('#result').load('codes/test.html', function(){prettyPrint();$('#result').show();});" >XHTML code</a>
```

load() takes a second argument which is a function to call when the load is done.  I moved the prettyPrint and the show to there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$('#result').show("fast",function(){ prettyPrint();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback function:

```
<a onclick="$('#result').load('codes/test.html', function() {prettyPrint();}).show();" >XHTML code</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you misunderstand how `.load()` works. It does not block until the data is loaded. Instead, it only *starts* loading and returns immediately. Therefore, your `prettyPrint` function gets called when the data is not loaded yet.

To fix this, pass a callback function to `.load`. That callback will be called when the load completes:

```
$("#result").load( '...',
    function() { 
        $("#result").show();
        prettyPrint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can make `load()` works synchronously... Just joking ^^